# Fast rgb565 to YUV (or even rgb565 to Y)

Tags: optimization, assembly, x86, yuv, blit

I'm working on a thing where I want to have the output option to go to a video overlay.  Some support rgb565,  If so sweet, just copy the data across.

If not I have to copy data across with a conversion and it's a frame buffer at a time.   I'm going to try a few things, but I thought this might be one of those things that optimisers would be keen on having a go at for a bit of a challenge.

There a variety of YUV formats that are commonly supported  easiest would be the Plane of Y followed by either interleaved or individual planes of UV.

Using Linux / xv,   but at the level I'm dealing with it's just bytes and an x86.

I'm going to focus on speed at the cost of quality, but there are potentially hundreds of different paths to try out.    There's a balance in there somewhere.

I looked at mmx but I'm not sure if there is anything useful there.  There's nothing that strikes me as particularly suited to the task and it's a lot of shuffling to get things into the right place in registers.

Trying a crude version with Y = Green*0.5 + R*0.25 + Blue*notmuch.   The U and V are even less of a concern quality wise.  You can get away with murder on those channels.

For a simple loop.

```
loop:
movzx eax,[esi]
add esi,2
shr eax,3
shr al,1
add ah,ah
add al,ah
mov [edi],al
add edi,1
dec count
jnz loop
```

of course every instruction depends on the one before and word reads aren't the best so interleaving two might gain a bit

```
loop: 
mov eax,[esi]
add esi,4
mov ebx,eax
shr eax,3
shr ebx,19
add ah,ah
add bh,bh
add al,ah
add bl,bh
mov ah,bl
mov [edi],ax
add edi,2
dec count
jnz loop
```

It would be quite easy to do that with 4 at a time, maybe for a benefit.

Can anyone come up with anything faster, better?

An interesting side point to this is whether or not a decent compiler can produce similar code.

Answer (score 1):

What you really want to look at, I think, is using MMX or the integer SSE instructions for this.  That will let you work with a few pixels at a time.  I imagine your compiler will be able to generate such code if you specify the correct switches, especially if your code is written nicely enough.

Regarding your existing codes, I wouldn't bother with interleaving instructions of different iterations to gain performance.  The out-of-order engine of all x86 processors (excluding Atom) and the caches should handle that pretty well.

**Edit:**  If you need to do horizontal adds you might want to use the `PHADDD` and `PHADDW` instructions.  In fact, if you have the Intel Software Designer's Manual, you should look for the `PH*` instructions.  They might have what you need.

Comment: I have looked at MMX and SSE.  I mentioned that in the summary.    I couldn't see anything particularly useful in this instance because MMX is hampered when performing horizontal operations.   The operation I need to perform is varying levels of multiplication (or shift) on different parts of the one input source. 

  PMADDWD is more or less the operation I need to perform but that requires getting the data into two words to generate a doubleword result which would then need to be extracted. 


I seriously doubt an out-of-order cpu could significantly speed the short version of that loop.

Comment: The PHADDW  and similar instructions  are SSSE3 I believe.  That cuts out too many systems.  Including My laptop.    All the good instructions are always just out of reach.

Answer (score 1):

A decent compiler, given the appropriate switches to tune for the CPU variants of most interest, almost certainly knows a lot more about good x86 instruction selection and scheduling than any mere mortal!

Take a look at the [Intel(R) 64 and IA-32 Architectures Optimization Reference Manual](http://www.intel.com/Assets/PDF/manual/248966.pdf)...

If you want to get into hand-optimising code, a good strategy might be to get the compiler to generate assembly source for you as a starting point, and then tweak that; profile before and after every change to ensure that you're actually making things better.

Comment: That's a quite a bit of faith you have there in the compiler.  Care to put it to the test?

Y  = (rgb565 & 0x7ff >> 4) + (rgb565 & 0xf800) >> 11  //dinner time so may be wrong :-)

which in asm is

shr eax,3;  
shr al,1;
add ah,ah;
add al,ah; 

And apart from partial register stalls is fairly compact.  I'm honestly curious as to whether a compiler takes the same, or better approach.

(I shall come back and figure out formatting after dinner)

Comment: Too slow.  Edit button's gone.  Lets try formatting 

For readability the code above was. 

`0x7ff >> 4) + (rgb565 & 0xf800) >> 11`

and (hopefully the same thing asm)

`shr eax,3;  shr al,1;  add ah,ah;  add al,ah`

.
Well that's not a whole lot better now either :-/